Cant type inside an iframe
When I code I like to put iframes but the problem is when I view the finished project and I try to type in the link it doesn't work
here is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Eaglercraft Site - Astra Client</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="astra client.jpeg">
  </head>
  <body><iframe src="https://raw.githack.com/BarneyCompiler/AstraClientEagler/main/javascript/EaglercraftX_1.8_Offline_International.html" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </body>
</html>

So then when I try to like type my username in the game when i view how it looks like it doesn't work
I tried different methods that I found on the internet such as an embed code but that doesn't work either. I didn't try anything else for the moment. I do know that without the iframe or embed just the link in a new tab I was able to type.

Please elaborate on how it's not working.

so for example when you play Minecraft. when you want to type in chat for example. It will not work. Or if you try to move using your WASD. It wont work everything else will work except key controls. I know that my keyboard isn't broken. Which is why i'm stuck

So the page appears for you inside the iframe. Do you get some errors in the browser console?

Try editing the iframe:
<iframe src='<link>' frameborder=0 style='overflow:hidden!important;overflow-x:hidden!important;overflow-y:hidden!important;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute!important;top:0%;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:9999!important;' height='99%' width='100%'></iframe>

then make an invisible button after the iframe:
<button onclick='this.iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.focus();' hidden>‎</button>


it works thanks!
